# Java - paycheck issue

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class PayCheckStatic
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        while (name!=null)
    {
            String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the next employees name" );
            String wage = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter their hourly wage?");
            String hoursWorked = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("How many hours did they work this last work?");

            double wages = Double.parseDouble(wage);
            double hours = Double.parseDouble(hoursWorked);

            calculatePay(name,wages,hours);
    }
}

private static void calculatePay(String name,double wages,double hours)
{
if (hours > 40)
        {
         double pay = ((wages * 40)+((hours - 40)*(1.5 * wages)));
        JOptionPane.ShowMessageDialog (null,name + "'s pay is £" + pay);
        }
    else
        {
        double pay = (wages * hours);
        JOptionPane.ShowMessageDialog (null,name + "'s pay is £" + pay);
        }
}

}
```

For some reason my code won't compile and it is coming up with cannot find symbol errors, and I can't work out why. The error is showing 3 times, with 2 of them on the message dialog boxes. Any tips as to how I can fix it?

Comment: Which lines are causing the errors? Can you show the exact error messages? These are the keys both for you and us to help find a solution. While you might get a solution here this time, next time you ask a question about an error (or about anything), please include all relevant information.

Answer (score 7):

Your main method starts with:

```
while(name != null)
```

but you have not declared name yet. You need to move the `String name` line before you while loop starts.

Answer (score 2):

As other have pointed out, you need fix your while loop in main because of name not being defined.

However, there is also another error: your calls to  `JOptionPane.ShowMessageDialog()` are incorrect.

The correct method you should be calling is `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()` (notice the camel case method name instead of pascal case)

Answer (score 1):

If the code you posted is indeed your full program, then you have an undefined `name` in your `main()` function.

You will either have to add a static variable names `name` in the class, so the static `main()` can access it or declare it locally in `main()`.  On a second look, you do have a `String name` declared, but after you are trying to use it.  Move the declaration of `name` before the `if()` in `main()`